# Is there a shortcut for inserting date/time in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to add date/time for comments so that I can know when I did those changes, and I am doing that by hand now because I could not find a shortcut. What a great plus for IntelliJ IDEA to have a shortcut for that!

Comment: Isn't this what version control is for?

Comment: verson control software can do that. But sometimes I want to add something with date/time in the code.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can create your own:

1. In Settings, go to Live Templates
2. Add a new template with the abbreviation "date"
3. For "template text", specify `$date$`.  Now the "Edit Variables" button should be enabled.
4. Edit the variables, and set `$date$` to use the expression `date()`.
5. Enable "Java comment" under the template's context and click OK.

Now when you type "date" and use the default completion gesture (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), it will replace "date" with the current date.

You can also make use of the `time()` expression.  Note that it doesn't seem like IntelliJ has great support for specifying the *format* of this date.

Comment: It seems they heard you... Now you can do date("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz") in the variable field.

Comment: Is there a way to add UTC time?

Comment: date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") it is working fine. e.g ( 2019-01-18 15:24:06 )

Comment: There are [other functions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/edit-template-variables-dialog.html#predefined_functions) you can use, like `timestamp()` which I use for exception codes.

Answer (score 22):

The `date()` and `time()` functions used by the live templates are based on standard java library functions. You can pass a standard java data/time formatter string as an argument to `date()` and `time()`. E.g. To get a timestamp like

```
2014-08-19T16:24:05.429Z
```

use in "Edit Template Variables" the variable expression:

```
date("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
```

to be assigned to the $date$ variable.

@Mark, Now IntelliJ has *great* support for specifying the date and time format ;-)

Comment: Your format only works if you are in the Time Zone 'UTC'. You should use date("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz") to insert the current date/time in a valid way.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful as I was exactly looking for this!

Answer (score 5):

Or you can just add the date whenever you create a new file by:

Settings > Editor | File and Code Templates > Includes (TAB) > File Header

Then type down something like:

```
/**
* Created by ${USER} on ${DAY} ${MONTH_NAME_SHORT}, ${YEAR} 
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good plugin for that called Referencer:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7104-referencer

> Current date/time formatted as YYYY-MM-DD and YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
>
> Current UNIX timestamp in seconds and milliseconds